# error running default servlet

Tags: java, maven, servlets, wildfly-10

i work in maven project, I created a pom maven project and 2 maven module
A module for the business layer (Ejb) and the other for the web layer (war maven project)
my problem is when i run a simple servlet wildfly show me 404 - Not Found

this is my Console output

```
18:53:18,813 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1 from [Module "deployment.BanquePPWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1 from [Module "deployment.BanquePPWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
... 6 more
18:53:18,992 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BanquePPWeb.war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1 from [Module \"deployment.BanquePPWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1 from [Module \"deployment.BanquePPWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
18:53:19,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "BanquePPWeb.war" (runtime-name : "BanquePPWeb.war")
18:53:19,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./BanquePPWeb.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1 from [Module "deployment.BanquePPWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4" id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>BanquePPWeb</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>Test1</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Test1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

[image: my project]

Comment: Have you read the error message/ It says that the class test.Test1 is not found. Do you have such a class? Where is it? What is the structure of your war file?

Comment: test.Test1 Already exists
I did a screenshot

Comment: Java files go under src/main/java in a Maven project. resources is for non Java files that must be loaded by the classloader at runtime.